# When does Refresh Token expires for Google Drive API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I just Started using Google Drive API using python to download File. I'm seeing it requires authentication for the first time and generates a **token.pickle** file. From next time onwards we can use this token file for API call.

**Note :** The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens.

**What I needed to know is when this token file will expire ?** If it expires then how to extend it's validity ?

I've gone through many google documentations but couldn't find anything clear regarding this.

If anyone can suggest me any info on this, that will be most welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

Refresh tokens shouldn't expire but they can.

1. If the user removes your access though their Google account the refresh token will expire
2. if the refresh token has not been used in six months it will expire.
3. When you a user authenticates your application you get an access token and refresh token, if they authenticate your application again, you will get another access token and refresh token.  You can have up to fifty refresh tokens for a users account and they will all work but after 50 the first one will expire.

Access tokens expire after an hour and you use the refresh token to request a new one.

## [Update for 2021](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Comment: Can the refresh token also expire if my Drive App (API) is not in production?

Comment: There is an unverified rumor (As in i haven't tested it personally yet and there is no documentation on it) that unverified apps in testing, seam to only have refresh tokens that last for two weeks.   If this is the case it was a stealth change by google they have not leased any official word on it.

Comment: Thank makes sense to me. Thank you. I think this happened to me as my work is still underdevelopment.

Comment: documented here https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en#publishing-status&zippy=%2Ctesting

Answer (score 0):

If your app's publishing status is in 'Testing', then the token will last for 2 weeks only.

If its publishing status is 'in Production' then the token has no expiry. However if any sensitive scopes are there and not verified in your app, then the number of users also limited.

These are all tested but seems no official documentation is available yet.