# Add xlsx documents to Google Drive shared folder using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm able to add CSVs to a shared google drive folder using Python, but I'm confused as what to change in my script to allow for excel documents. Here is my code for CSV.

```
def publish_to_drive(folder_id, path_to_file, filename):
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    file_metadata = {
        'name': filename,
        'parents': [folder_id],
        'mimeType': 'text/csv'
    }
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(path_to_file, mimetype='text/csv', 
                                 resumable=True)
    resp = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media_body,supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

I realize that the mimetypes need to be changed, but I'm not sure what they need to be changed to.  I've tried various ones but have not been able to get the right ones.

Upon using the right mimetypes I get the following when attempting to open the excel file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't an issue on using function on `text/csv` file types, then I believe you only need to update your `mimetype` from `text/csv` into `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

I've added some resources/links below that lists other mime types if you need your function to work on them too.

To actually support multiple mime types, you need to dynamically identify the `mimetype` for each file type. You can do it by either:

- Simple string manipulation (if you see a pattern) or have a conditional statement on each `mimetype` you want to support (both not recommended)
- Or for universality, like [this](https://github.com/jbmorley/google-drive-upload/blob/master/google-drive-upload#L99).

#### Resources:

- [Microsoft mime types](https://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.html)
- [Google apps mime types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)
- [IANA mime types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)
- [Python drive uploader](https://github.com/jbmorley/google-drive-upload/blob/master/google-drive-upload#L99)

Comment: This appears to work, but the excel files in Google Drive are corrupted.

Comment: Hi @ben890, you might want to try other file types as well to check what's wrong. identify which part of the code returns wrongly. was it returning wrong mimetypes? or just a certain filetype that are corrupted? You might need to debug since so far it does work, just corrupted. There maybe a line there that should be fixed or replaced. Good luck. Hopefully you can fix the corrupted issue.

Comment: So the code executes fine, it's just the resulting file doesn't open.

Comment: Interestingly, those mimetypes work when it's an xlsx file with only one tab.  When I attempt to use multiple tabs I get the error in the picture I posted in the question.

Comment: And I attempted to download the file and the resulting file is corrupted.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out! I wasn't closing the excel writer before uploading th efile.Than you @NaziA